# How to lookup into another table using EDT AX 2012

Tags: x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I'm just starting with AX 2012. I need to show exchange rate type (as a combo field, that shows a detail look up downwards - standard behavior of ax) on purchase parameter form.

I have tried to add column to purchase parameter table based on EDT exchangeRateTypeName(array) and added the group to "srmPurchParameter" form. But its showing as string (no editable). I am expecting the combo with drop box look up.

Comment: Add a referencefield to the form. Not a string field.
I think (will check tomorrow) it only auto creates the combobox if the relationship is set up correct between the two tables.

Comment: hi Sir Troll                                                          i was missing the relationship btw two tables. after adding correct foreign key relationship on purchase parameter table, i'm sorted. thanks anyways.

PS. adding reference field to table is used for custom filter, correct me if wrong. i also wanted to save the combo value to purchase parameter table.

Comment: In some cases you don't wish to make a foreign key. You can then create your own ReferenceGroup to make this combobox happen.